# 4 GB Onboard memory, 1 x SO-DIMM socket , total up to 8 GB SDRAM

Tags: memory

My laptop model is # ASUS Laptop 15 X509JA (core i3 10th generation)

Website link # https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-Laptop-15-X509JA/specifications/

In specification It says #
4 GB Onboard memory, 1 x SO-DIMM socket , total up to 8 GB SDRAM

Can anyone please let me know, total how much extra RAM i can attach? Whether it will be ddr3 or, ddr4? What bus speed it should be?

Answer (score 0):

DDR4, 2400MHz, Non-ECC, CL17, 1.2V, Unbuffered, 260-pin SODIMM

The statement "4 GB Onboard memory, 1 x SO-DIMM socket , total up to 8 GB SDRAM" in the specs is a little deceiving as it is telling you how much memory you can ADD to the system, in this case a 8GB stick of RAM.

According to [Kingston's Memory Configurator for the Asus X509 series](https://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search?model=100412&devicetype=3&mfr=ASU&line=X%20Series%20Notebook) the maximum memory is 12 GB with 4GB onboard RAM , or 16 GB with 8GB onboard RAM.

According to [Crucial Memory](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/x509jb), [CDW's Memory Selector](https://www.cdw.com/content/cdw/en/product-finders/memory.html#/result/4030601), and [Newegg's Memory configurator](https://www.newegg.com/tools/memory-finder/#/result/4030601) this will actually support an added 16GB DIMM to be added to give you a total of 20GB (or 24GB if you had 8GB onboard RAM) as the maximum memory.

Remember, within some limits you can generally install RAM that is faster than you have already and the system's firmware will just slow down how it addresses it.

I would agree with the last three sites as that this should support a 16GB SODIMM for a maximum of 20GB with no issues. The Intel 300 series chipset with an Intel 10th Generation processor should handle 64GB of RAM without issue, although mainboard firmware limitations may prohibit adding a single 32GB SODIMM, although technically it should work and give you a total of 36GB or RAM.